# Problem with Python environments and Slurm (sbatch)

Tags: python, hpc, slurm, sbatch

I'm running into a problem when I try to run a batch job on a SLURM HPC cluster.

The .py file runs well on my HPC user directory.
However, when I run it on a GPU using sbatch command, it throws:

> slurmstepd: error: execve(): /var/spool/slurm/d/job401100/slurm_script:
> Not a directory

My Python versions:

```
$ python -V
Python 2.7.5
$ python3 -V
Python 3.6.8
```

test.py runs on python3.

Example Python code inside test.py:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score, confusion_matrix,classification_report
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
from sklearn.naive_bayes import MultinomialNB

true = pd.read_csv("testfile.csv")
print('Just Testing. End for now.')
```

gpu.job :

```
#!/bin/bash/

#SBATCH --job-name=testgpu       # Job name
#SBATCH --output=job.%j.out      # Name of output file (%j expands to jobId)
#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=4        # Schedule one core
#SBATCH --gres=gpu               # Schedule a GPU
#SBATCH --time=71:59:59          # Run time (hh:mm:ss) - run for one hour max
#SBATCH --partition=red          # Run on either the Red or Brown queue
#SBATCH --mail-type=END          # Send an email when the job finishes
#SBATCH --export=ALL             # All of the users environment will be loaded from callers environment


python3 test.py
```

I understand that when slurm executes a script, it does so in its own slurm directory and environment - it as no knowledge of my environment unless I specifically tell it about it.
However, including `"--export=ALL"` into the job file does not help.

How could I fix this issue?

Comment: `#!/bin/bash/` is a typo?

Comment: Thank you for the note. Yes, it was a problem. After changing it, I run into a different situation.
If in the top of the gpu.job I have #!/usr/bin/python3 (I got this after checking 'which python'), then the output file complains "invalid syntax in line 13" (python3 test.py).

Comment: In another case, if I put "import sys
print(sys.version)
print(sys.path)" 
instead of 'python3 test.py' in the job file, it executes well:

3.6.8 (default, Aug  7 2019, 17:28:10)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39)]
['/var/spool/slurm/d/job40233', '/usr/lib64/python36.zip', '/usr/lib64/python3.6', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/ieja/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib64/python3.6/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python3.6/site-packages']
Hello World
---> DONE
~